# MYSQL SELECT * doesn't work with GROUP BY and HAVING

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, having

```
SELECT * FROM or_mail
GROUP BY campaign_id
HAVING date_time = MAX(date_time);

SELECT campaign_id, date_time FROM or_mail
GROUP BY campaign_id
HAVING date_time = MAX(date_time);
```

The 1st query returns 13 records. The 2nd returns 35.

Why are records missing from the first query!? Why should what I'm selecting matter at all?

Comment: `HAVING date_time = MAX(date_time)` doesn't mean anything in SQL. It's nonsense. You seem to be trying to do a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] query, so go find one of the many solutions posted on StackOverflow for that type of query.

Comment: @BillKarwin how is that a duplicate question. I think my query should be valid, and I really want to know why it doesn't work. Because I think my query is much easier to read, I don't want to use JOINS if I don't have to.

Comment: Think of it this way: in a language like PHP or Java or whatever, suppose I write a comparison like `if (arrayvar = max(arrayvar)`. Is this true or false? It's true for a given element of the array, but not for the *whole* array. The comparison doesn't make sense. Likewise it doesn't make sense to do this in SQL, because the `HAVING` clause applies to groups, not to rows.

Answer (score 2):

This is your query:

```
SELECT campaign_id, date_time
FROM or_mail
GROUP BY campaign_id
HAVING date_time = MAX(date_time);
```

You are aggregating by `campaign_id`.  That means that the results will have one row per `campaign_id`.  What `date_time` goes on the row?  Well, an *arbitrary* value from one of the matching rows.  Just one value, an arbitrary one.  The same is true of the `having` clause.  In other words, the query does not do what you expect it to do.

Whether you know it or not, you are using a `group by` extension that is particular to MySQL (you can read the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html)).  The documentation specifically warns against using the extension this say.  (There would be no problem if `date_time` were the same on all rows with the same `campaign_id`, but that is not the case.)

The following is the query that you actually want:

```
SELECT campaign_id, date_time
FROM or_mail om
WHERE not exists (select 1
                  from or_mail om2
                  where om2.campaign_id = om.campaign_id and
                        om2.date_time > date_time
                 );
```

What this says is:  Return results from all rows in `or_mail` with the property that there is no larger `date_time` with the same `campaign_id`.
    HAVING date_time = MAX(date_time);

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't... Did you wait a while before running second query? If so, then a bunch of records could have been created.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure it's the query that's doing this, I've tested a lot of variations. If I have to, I'll build a test using sqlfiddle or something.